# OpenCL: One Program running one multiple devices

Tags: opencl

I found already this
[OpenCL: Running CPU/GPU multiple devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5647795/opencl-running-cpu-gpu-multiple-devices).

But i've stil questions (3) how to run a programm on multiple devices. Is the recipe as follows?(Q1)

1. create the devices you want to use.
2. For every device create a context.
3. for every context call clBuilProgram to build a program
4. for every program call clCreateCommandQueue to build one command queue per context
5. for every context and for every function parameter call clCreateBuffer.

or must i concatenate the CommandQueues.(Q2)

Has someone some example code or a link to a tutorial? (Q3)

Comment: What are the device types you wish to use, CPU & GPU?   Unfortunately OpenCL programs need to tuned (code can be quite different)  for each device type. I restrict my  OpenCL multiple device type work to running on matched pairs of GPUs.

Comment: No, i just want to run the algorithm on multiple GPUs (same vendor).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You create a single context containing all the devices. Context construction takes a list of devices. You compile the program once for the context. You call clBuildProgram, or clCompileProgram and clLinkProgram once for the program, listing all the devices or not listing any devices and letting it build for all in the context. Create a command queue for each device in the context. Create a buffer for each array you want access to. If you want to process different parts of the array on different devices you can either create two buffers, or use sub-buffers to divide it into sections.

If you are not happy with the same program targeting all devices and want to optimise further you can create a separate program for each device, or create the program once and call clCompileProgram separately for each device passing in macros.

Comment: Does this mean i can create a single context for devices from different Device-Types ( and or different Plattforms)?

Comment: Not different platforms, no. One context per platform should work.

Answer (score 1):

If all of the devices that you are targetting come from the same platform then @Lee's response is fine (e.g. AMD GPUs + CPU, or Intel GPUs + CPU). If you expect to have to target a mix of platforms (e.g. combining Nvidia GPUs with AMD GPUs and a CPU) then your contexts cannot cross from one platform to another - at the very least, you will need one context per platform.

The options as I see it are:

1. One device per context. Synchronization between devices requires copying to host memory.
2. Multiple devices in one context, only using one platform. This can make it easier to share data between devices in the same context.
3. Multiple devices from the same platform in one context, one context per platform. Allows you to concurrently utilise multiple platforms while giving you the benefits of having multiple devices in one context.

Option 3 gets a bit tricky in the work distribution because you have two levels at which work gets divided - between contexts/platforms and between devices. Option 1 is, IMHO, the easiest way to get access to every OpenCL device in a computer, irrespective of their platform. Option 2 is only really worthwhile if you are guaranteed to always be working on devices from one vendor (i.e. all devices in one platform). That assumption breaks pretty quickly if targeting GPU+CPU simultaneously.

Once you have worked through the above three options, you will need at least one command queue **per device**. You will need to compile your OpenCL kernels for every group of identical devices. Every generation of GPUs from every vendor is different. At the very least, you could end up with macros that have different deffinitions from one device to another. At worst, you could have different algorithms from one device to another (easier to handle if using Option 1 above).

Comment: Options 2 and 3 are also likely more efficient in many cases because dependencies and data motion can be handled in the driver stack (and maybe by the device itself) without kicking the application thread back onto the CPU. They are pretty likely situations to be in if you are either on a mobile SoC (where you're not very likely to get two different platforms at all) or have a multi-GPU desktop where most people buy from the same vendor and this would allow direct GPU->GPU memory transfers.

Comment: In practice on Linux I am finding that the Intel CPU and IGP (NEO) runtimes do produce two separate platforms, which means that at least for these Intel systems we're looking at option 1 making the most sense.